# Symfony KnpBundle пагинация с GroupBy и DATE_FORMAT

Tags: php, symfony

Есть следующий код:

```
        $queryBuilder = $em->createQueryBuilder();

        $queryBuilder->from(StatVisit::class, 'v');
        $queryBuilder->addselect('count(v.id) as visitCount');
        $queryBuilder->addselect('DATE_FORMAT(v.createdAt, \'%Y-%m-%d\') as day');
        $queryBuilder->groupby('day');

        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $queryBuilder, /* query NOT result */
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
            10/*limit per page*/
        );
```

Запрос с группировкой по дате. Без пагинации - все работает хорошо. Когда использую пагинацию, то выдается ошибка:

> Notice: Undefined index: day

Пагинатор - KnpPaginatorBundle

Если делать

```
$queryBuilder->groupby('DATE_FORMAT(v.createdAt, \'%Y-%m-%d\') as day')
```

То не находится функция DATE_FORMAT. Хотя дополнения установлены, да и в select она работает.

Собственно как сделать пагинацию? Вариант, что отдать в пагинатор результат, а не билдер - знаю, но это крайний случай.

Answer (score 0):

Помогло установка опций `['distinct' => false, 'wrap-queries' => true]`

```
 $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $queryBuilder, /* query NOT result */
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
            10/*limit per page*/,
            ['distinct' => false, 'wrap-queries' => true]
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

*Боюсь предположить, что необходимо добавить к запросу: ->getQuery()*

```
$queryBuilder->groupby('DATE_FORMAT(v.createdAt, \'%Y-%m-%d\') as day')->getQuery()
```

Comment: К сожалению, это не решает проблему. Пагинатор принимает как билдер, так и запрос.

Comment: Я попытался проделать такое у себя и оказалось, что там получается 2 массива. По крайней мере у меня, когда попытался вывести всю информацию в таблицу.
Получалось что я получаю: массив из 2 объектов, один из v, а другой day.
[0=> [0=> ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Vasya'], day => '2019-08-20']]
Примерно что то вроде этого.